# How can an Android background thread detect if another activity is active and ready to receive data?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-activity, background

Background: I'm using Eclipse to develop an Android application that plots Bluetooth data on a Android phone in real-time. It consists primarily of a Bluetooth Activity, a background thread created by the Bluetooth Activity, and a Plotting Activity.

The primary focus of my question: Is there a mechanism for the Bluetooth background thread to detect if the Plotting Activity is active and ready to somehow receive the BluetoothData? Or better, can the background thread be listening for some event that tells it the Plotting Activity is active?

This is open source code that I am hacking on. With Logcat I have deduced that the Bluetooth Activity must have created some sort of background thread that continues to produce new BluetoothData even when I switch to my Plotting Activity.

Eventually, I found the method in the background thread that writes the BluetoothData to Logcat. So I feel I should be able to leverage this method to somehow "stream", as it where, the BluetoothData to the Plotting Activity or something **if only it could determine the Plotting Activity is active.**

So that's my question. But maybe I am going in the wrong direction? Maybe I just somehow send the thread's data and check some result code to see if it worked. If so, I'm in business. Otherwise the other activity was not active. I don't really like this approach, because I would be polling to see if the other activity was active.

Any suggestions?

Comment: OK my first mistake: You can't call onCreate() yourself. Or can you? Android does that. So I am stumped as to how to ever call a regular instance method that belongs to a class that extends Activity. Make the call after the activity has been launched?

Comment: You've got this back to front!! Firstly, onCreate should only be called by the android system. Secondly, the activity should only be instantiated by the android system. When done properly, activities cannot talk directly to each other, but must do so via a Service or Intents or similar

Comment: @Jodes, what does "back to front" mean? First, as for Android calling onCreate() I kind of figured that out above. Second, the Activities are instantiated by Android, except the call to plotData(). @Femi says I can call plotData() like this in my background thread. I do have quite a good background thread if you haven't noticed.

Comment: This question was edited to focus on a single clearer more precise question.

Comment: It doesn't sounds right. There are a questions you have to answer before deciding on the design - if plotting activity is NOT running - do you have to collect the bluetooth data anyway? If not then you should re-design the app to start bluetooth thread only when plotting activity starts and stop it when it closes..

Comment: @denis Running the Bluetooth activity first is by design. It lets the user see the data before it is plotted. And gives us keypad for changing the data output format. So no I won't be redesigning this part.

Comment: @Vince do you need to plot real-time data in the plotting activity - meaning update it when new data comes. or just plot what you have shown in the bluetooth activity?

Comment: @Denis I am already updating the plot in real-time as new data comes in from background thread that was started by bluetooth activity. If I switch back to the Bluetooth activity, it resumes scrolling the data across the screen in real-time. This is where I can make changes to the rate, format, and number of channels and switch back to the plotting activity to see the affect on the real-time plotting activity. My questions continue to evolve. My current solution is to have the background thread call a static method in my Plotting activity. But I have been advised this not the right solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this question is answered based on the comments.